# xcparse command in post-actions script always returns error

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

I've set up an XCUITest target to automatically make screenshots. What I'm trying to do is automate the export of those screenshots. To do this I'm writing this bash script:

```bash
exec > "${PROJECT_DIR}/post_test.log" 2>&1
set -o pipefail
set -e

subparent="$(dirname "$BUILD_DIR")"
derived_data="$(dirname "$subparent")"
test_result_folder="$derived_data/Logs/Test"
files=($test_result_folder/*.xcresult)
filename=${files[@]: -1}

echo "DerivedData path: $derived_data"
echo "Test result folder: $test_result_folder"
echo "Files:"
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
echo "\nMost recent is $filename"

echo /opt/homebrew/bin/xcparse attachments ${filename} ${PROJECT_DIR}/Screenshots | pbcopy

/opt/homebrew/bin/xcparse attachments $filename ${PROJECT_DIR}/Screenshots
```

The issue here is that the `xcparse`command always returns an error, but if I paste the same command in the terminal it works perfectly. The error is

```
Error: “/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dhlyvtxfzjxxazcadignzodednxi/Logs/Test/Test-MyAppScreenshotsUITests-2023.03.31_12-27-42-+0200.xcresult” does not appear to be an xcresult
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: @CSolanaM Yes, this is the final script I'm using. Check it here https://gist.github.com/andrealufino/6560a36271025619a214ba3fece175cc.

Comment: I see, you ended up copying it to clipboard and performing the last step manually. I also ended up creating a standalone bash script, so no clue what was going on in our cases :D

Comment: @CSolanaM Computers my friend, we chose a funny career 